# Словари в Phyton

Tags: python, словари

подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка, не могу понять.
Заранее спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В кавычках. Используйте одинарные в alien_1['color'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если вы используете строку, ограниченную одним типом кавычек, то используйте внутри строки другой тип кавычек

```
print(f"{alien_1['color']}")
```

или

```
print(f'{alien_1["color"]}')
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.